# Linq - Boolean - where statement

Tags: c#, linq, boolean

I have the below code which I am struggling with.

```
var q = from hed in cxt.SOPOrderReturns.ToExpandable()
        join cus in cxt.SLCustomerAccounts 
              on hed.CustomerID equals cus.SLCustomerAccountID
        join ad in cxt.SOPDocDelAddresses 
              on hed.SOPOrderReturnID equals ad.SOPOrderReturnID
        where hed.AnalysisCode1 == "SO"
        select new
        {
            hed.SOPOrderReturnID,
            hed.DocumentNo,
            hed.DocumentDate,
            cus.CustomerAccountNumber,
            Route = hed.AnalysisCode2,
            Drop = hed.AnalysisCode5,
            hed.ReadyForInvoicePrint,
        };

q = q.RemoveExpandable();

return q;
```

The column hed.ReadyForInvoicePrint is Boolean and I want to add a where statement which also shows if the column is FALSE.

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 3):

You can filter on `false` value of this column by adding `&& !hed.ReadyForInvoicePrint` to your `where` statement.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are asking I believe you want to have the ability to query on a number of parameters. You can simply add a variable for doing this.

```
var q = from hed in cxt.SOPOrderReturns.ToExpandable()
var someVar = true | false;
join cus in cxt.SLCustomerAccounts on hed.CustomerID equals 
cus.SLCustomerAccountID
join ad in cxt.SOPDocDelAddresses on hed.SOPOrderReturnID equals 
ad.SOPOrderReturnID
where hed.AnalysisCode1 == "SO" && hed.ReadyForInvoicePrint == someVar

select new
{
hed.SOPOrderReturnID,
hed.DocumentNo,
hed.DocumentDate,
cus.CustomerAccountNumber,
Route = hed.AnalysisCode2,
Drop = hed.AnalysisCode5,
hed.ReadyForInvoicePrint,

};

q = q.RemoveExpandable();

return q;
```

Alternatively you can wrap you query into an IQueryable where clauses can be conditionally added at later point in your code.

```
private IQueriable<SOPOrderReturns> GetSOPOrderReturnsQuery(){
var q = from hed in cxt.SOPOrderReturns.ToExpandable()
join cus in cxt.SLCustomerAccounts on hed.CustomerID equals 
cus.SLCustomerAccountID
join ad in cxt.SOPDocDelAddresses on hed.SOPOrderReturnID equals 
ad.SOPOrderReturnID

select new
{
hed.SOPOrderReturnID,
hed.DocumentNo,
hed.DocumentDate,
cus.CustomerAccountNumber,
Route = hed.AnalysisCode2,
Drop = hed.AnalysisCode5,
hed.ReadyForInvoicePrint,

};

q = q.RemoveExpandable();

return q.AsQueryable();
}
```

Getting the query and making alterations

```
var query = GetSOPOrderReturnsQuery();
query = query.Where(x=>x.AnalysisCode1 == "SO");
query = query.Where(x=>x.ReadyForInvoicePrint == false);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help very new to Linq but the first option && hed. etc... worked for me  the problem I had appeared to be me putting == False where it will only accept ==false   Didn't realise it was case sensitive